# Que un botón haga una cosa después de otra

Tags: javascript, html

quería saber como hacer un botón que primero aumente el tamaño del texto y luego lo reestablezca a su valor original pero solo puedo aumentar su tamaño

```
  <button id="1">a</button>
```

```
boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    lista.style.fontSize = "110%"
});
```

Comment: @AgustinG. Quería que al apretar el botón aumente el tamaño del texto, luego al apretar el mismo botón ese texto vuelva a su tamaño anterior, no sé si se puede o nop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo guardaría en un objeto con el objeto y si está activado o no para realizar luego lo que quieras.

De esta manera tal vez para otras funciones necesites acceder a si está apretado o no el botón

```js
const p = document.querySelector("p");
var boton = {
  obj: document.querySelector("#boton"),
  encendido: false
}

boton.obj.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(!boton.encendido){
     boton.encendido = true;
     p.style.fontSize = "24px";
   } else {
     boton.encendido = false;
     p.style.fontSize = "16px";
   }
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size 16px;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton">Presionar</button>
<p>Texto de prueba</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma es agregando un setTimeOut luego de lo que ya tenes. Para que despues de una determinada cantidad de tiempo (en este caso 1000 milisegundos) vuelva a su tamaño original.

```js
const boton = document.getElementById("1");
const lista = document.getElementById("lista");
boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    lista.style.fontSize = "110%"
    
    setTimeout(() => {
    lista.style.fontSize = "100%"
    }, 1000)
});
```

```html
 <button id="1">Click me</button>
 <div id="lista">
   Yo seria el elemento lista
 </div>
```

Comment: Creo que se refería a que cuando presione el botón se agrande el texto, y que al volver al presionar vuelva a como estaba antes

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar operadores ternarios agregando una condición para llamar a la función que deseas en ese momento para el botón

```
boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
     condicion ? agrandarTexto() : achicarTexto()
});
```

Obviamente tendrás que crear las funciones agrandarTexto y achicarTexto y después llamarlas en el evento.